# 1000 users can read the single text at same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my website im having one csv file, which is having millions of records.
based on some search key i need to select one record. 
this part i completed. 
my doubt is **If multiple users (1000 users)** access my website (only one csv file will be available)... we can able to read the same file with 100 users?

Comment: Why don't you use a real database for this? Why do people use Csv files or excel sheets as databases? i will never understand that.

Comment: I agree with @Tim and Botz3000 - store the content of the file in a table, it will make your life easier

Comment: Technically a csv is a database and this will work if the file is not locked, however it's not recommended due to the excess file accessing, so a (conventional) database that buffers data into memory for sharing is a better solution

Comment: What do you mean by accessing the CSV file? do you want to serve the CSV file as is (the raw file actually), or do you want to access its content with a DB like operation?

Comment: @Steve B ,it is just text file.. im not using any db link.. using my c# codeing im reading the file

Comment: In this case, why don't you serve simply the csv file as a static content, and let IIS handle the cache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1M records is not a lot. Frankly I'd just load it all into structured data, and reference that. Any number of users can access it once it is memory (especially for read-only).

But ultimately the ideal answer here is: use a database. SQL Server Express is free and will cope with that effortlessly.

Comment: yes if i use database it ll be faster.. but here in this case my situation is i can't use database..

So if 1000 users accessing my website at same time.. then also it will work?

Comment: @SaravanaManikandan if you try to access that on the file-system, reading the CSV from scratch each time: it won't work well. Hence why I said load it into memory.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the application only has to read you will not have a problem. However it would be more efficent to use a database for this task. You can make indexes and use sql of easy access. No need to parse the file on each request and you can even add/change data when your site is running.

Comment: but here in this case my situation is i can't use database.. 
thanks for your answer..